# Algoritmo para cálculo de dígito verificador

Tags: algoritmo

> Crie um algoritmo para pedir um código (COD) de cinco algarismos, e gere o dígito (DIGV) verificador módulo 7 para o referido código.
>
> Supondo que os cinco algarismos do código são ABCDE, uma forma de calcular o dígito desejado, com módulo de 7 é:
>
> ```
> S = (6xA) + (5xB) + (4xC) + (3xD) + (2xE)
> DIGV = resto da divisão S por 7
> ```
>
> Utilize os operadores de quociente e resto

Eu pensei em desenvolver esse exercício transformando no que o usuário irá digitar em uma string, pegar cada índice dessa string e armazenar numa variável,e  fazer as contas, o que você acham? Alguém poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: Pode ser em qualquer linguagem?

Comment: Pode sim @rray, sem problemas!

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que

```
S = (6xA) + (5xB) + (4xC) + (3xD) + (2xE)
DIGV = resto da divisão S por 7
```

Seria equivalente a

```
S = (6 * A) + (5 * B) + (4 * C) + (3 * D) + (2 * E)
DIGV = S % 7;
```

Já podemos implementar em diversas linguagens, lembrando que A, B, C, D e E são dígitos de COD. Implementando em Javascript:

```
COD_NUM = 55480;
COD = COD_NUM+"";

A = parseInt(COD.charAt(0));
B = parseInt(COD.charAt(1));
C = parseInt(COD.charAt(2));
D = parseInt(COD.charAt(3));
E = parseInt(COD.charAt(4));

S = (6 * A) + (5 * B) + (4 * C) + (3 * D) + (2 * E);
DIGV = S % 7;
```

[Demonstração](http://ideone.com/xZjZS8)

Answer (score 2):

## Python

Em Python, é possível fazer da seguinte forma:

```py
code = "55480"

def get_divg (code):

    code = map(int, code)
    weights = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

    return sum(w * c for w, c in zip(weights, code)) % 7

print(get_divg(code))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/FXmUTP).

Convertemos primeiro a *string* para uma lista de inteiros utilizando `map`; fazemos o produto interno entre o código e seus respectivos pesos através da *list comprehensions*; somamos todos os valores através da função `sum` e finalmente obtemos o resto de divisão por 7 com o operador `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Não levando em considerações especificidades de linguagens (dado o tema de `Algoritmos`):

---

Sua solução parece adequada. Você pode tomar a entrada do usuário como uma `string` e trabalhar com cada caractere. Tenha, contato, o cuidado de fazer os cálculos com os algarismos equivalentes àqueles caracteres.

Por exemplo: caso o usuário digite `12345`, teríamos `A = 1`, não `A = '1'` (`A` é o algarismo `1`, não o caractere `'1'` que possui valor inteiro decimal igual a `49`, vide a [Tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

---

Uma outra solução possível seria ler a entrada do usuário, caractere a caractere, num laço. Esta solução é bastante similar à anterior. A maior diferença seria o fato de a entrada ser tomada caractere por caractere, não a string completa.

---

Uma terceira saída seria tomar o valor inteiro digitado pelo usuário e utilizar divisões inteiras para encontrar os caracteres de cada posição.

Dessa forma, para uma entrada `12345` e considerando que:

- o operador `//` nos dê o resultado da divisão inteira;
- o operador `%` nos dê o resultado do resto da divisão inteira.

Teríamos:

```
Entrada <- 12345
X <- Entrada

A <- X // 10000
X <- X % 10000

B <- X // 1000
X <- X % 1000

C <- X // 100
X <- X % 100

D <- X // 10
X <- X % 10

E <- X
```

---

Provavelmente há outras formas de realizar esta operação, mas essas são algumas que eu consegui pensar.

Eu acredito que a mais simples (aliando a questão de implementação e de clareza de código para outros) é a primeira, também sugerida por você.

Answer (score -2):

Fiz usando a classe JOptionPane para criar uma caixa de dialogo.

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Codigo, DigitoV, A, B, C, D, E, S;
        String  CampoA, CampoB, CampoC, CampoD, CampoE;

```
    CampoA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira A", "A", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    A = Integer.valueOf(CampoA);
    CampoB = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira B", "B", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    B = Integer.valueOf(CampoB);
    CampoC = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira C", "C", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    C = Integer.valueOf(CampoC);
    CampoD = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira D", "D", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    D = Integer.valueOf(CampoD);
    CampoE = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira E", "E", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    E = Integer.valueOf(CampoE);

    Codigo = A+B+C+D+E;
    S = (6*A) + (5*B) + (4*C) + (3*D) + (2*E);
    DigitoV = S % 7;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Digito V é: "+ DigitoV +  " Obrigado!!!");
```